# How to define static const member?

Tags: c++, g++, constants, static-members

My `Test` class has a `const` `static` member of a subtype. I usually define this `const` `static` member as follows.

```
class Test 
{
public:
    class Dummy {};

private:
    static Dummy const dummy;

};

Test::Dummy const Test::dummy;             // ERROR HERE

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this source with gcc-4.6, it gives no error and compiles correctly.

When compiling this same source with gcc-4.4, it gives the following error:
`error: uninitialized const ‘Test::dummy’`
on the marked line.

- Is there another way to define this static const member variable?
- Is this a limitation of gcc-4.4?
- Is there a workaround?

Comment: `Test::Dummy const Test::dummy = Test::Dummy();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say:

```
Test::Dummy const Test::dummy = { };
```

Comment: Should work as long as `Test::Dummy` is aggregate (C++03), or always in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

See http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#uninitialized_const (which gives the relevant reference to the standard) and also the [GCC 4.6 release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html#cplusplus) which say

> In 4.6.0 and 4.6.1 G++ no longer allows objects of const-qualified type to be default initialized unless the type has a user-declared default constructor. In 4.6.2 G++ implements the proposed resolution of DR [253](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#253), so default initialization is allowed if it initializes all subobjects. Code that fails to compile can be fixed by providing an initializer e.g.

```
struct A { A(); };
struct B : A { int i; };
const B b = B();
```

> Use -fpermissive to allow the old, non-conforming behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you could also add a default ctor to `class Dummy`:

```
class Dummy { public: Dummy(){} };
```

in line 4.

EDIT:
It appears that gcc 4.4 fails to generate the default ctor for class `Dummy`. Thus the above overcomes this compiler bug directly.

Comment: No need for that, `Dummy` has a compiler-synthesized default constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza well, under gcc 4.3.2, the above fixed the problem *without* any other changes to the original code

Comment: @juanchopanza indeed, a compiler bug: gcc 4.3.2 (and 4.4) fails to generate the default ctor. But that means that adding the default ctor *does* fix the problem at its core!

Comment: GCC does **not** fail to generate the default constructor, the standard doesn't allow it to be used there, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#uninitialized_const

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely does that mean that the first comment above by  juanchopanza was simply wrong?

Comment: The first comment is correct, Dummy has an implicitly-defined default constructor, but you can't use it to default-initialize a `const` object. That's not a compiler bug. See the details at the link I gave, which I wrote so I wouldn't have to keep repeating myself. A const object needs either a **user-defined** default constructor **or** an initializer. Adding an initializer allows the implicitly-defined default ctor to be used. Adding a user-defined default ctor means you don't need an initializer. That's why either change fixed the problem. Still not a compiler bug though.

Comment: Think about it, if GCC 4.4 failed to generate the default constructor then how come `Test::Dummy const Test::dummy = Test::Dummy();` works? That calls the default constructor that you claim doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc 4.4, use

```
Test::Dummy const Test::dummy = Test::Dummy;
```

With compilers supporting C++11, you can use uniform initialization syntax:

```
Test::Dummy const Test::dummy = { };
```

But I don't think that's supported by gcc 4.4.

Comment: your first solution doesn't work on gcc 4.3.2, but the second (a la Kerrek SB) does.

Comment: The first one should use `Test::Dummy()` not `Test::Dummy`. For the second one, uniform initialization syntax would be without the `=` i.e. `Test::Dummy const Test::dummy{ };`